# Error Con sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Tengo un problema con mi sublime text 3, me sale a cada rato este mensaje, ¿Saben cuál es la solución?

Estoy usando Windows 10.

> plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until sublime text has been restarted

Comment: Lo único que compilo es jade y sass, ademas mi maquina es regularmente potente,

Comment: Hay plugins que en sublime text3 no funcionan correctamente, busca información del paquete que tienes isntalado y mira la compatibilidad de versión.

Comment: si trasladas el erro lo que dice es que el plugin de sublime no va a funcionar hasta que reinicie sublime

Answer (score 2):

En general dicho plugin puede "crashear" (romperse) por varias razones. Puede ser algún otro plugin que hayas actualizado y tenga algún error o el propio Sublime.

En estos casos, el consejo que te daría es ir desactivando plugins uno a uno, abriendo y cerrando Sublime, y así encontrar quién es el culpable.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente es por que algún complemento tiene algún error, verifica la integridad de cada uno que tengas instalado.

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes muchos plugins instalados. Te recomendaría anotarlos, desinstalar sublime, borrar los directorios de instalación y volver a instalar. Algunas veces algún fichero se corrompe debido a actualizaciones o por el propio uso.

Answer (score 0):

buenas noches, he instalado sublime text 3, luego de configurar el PATCH por go, instale Phyton, y desde entonces me da las siguientes notificaciones que no se cómo corregir:

```
package github.com/DamnWidget/godef: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/fatih/motion: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/josharian/impl: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/nsf/gocode: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/zmb3/gogetdoc: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package gopkg.in/alecthomas/gometalinter.v1: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
[Finished in 5.7s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: C:\Go\bin\go get -x -u github.com/DamnWidget/godef golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru github.com/fatih/motion github.com/josharian/impl github.com/nsf/gocode github.com/zmb3/gogetdoc gopkg.in/alecthomas/gometalinter.v1]
[dir: C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3]
[path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-Win32;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Cracklock\Bin;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para corregir estas notificaciones?